# Null Pointer Exception while insert query

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have created a table in sqlite using an external Software and added to my project "assets" folder.  So far its working, but when i try to insert a query line from my application, it shows Null pointer Exception. Below is my coding, Pls help me find out if there is any wrong statement.

DatabaseOpenHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "peer.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

DatabaseAccess.java

```
public class DatabaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;
private Cursor cursor;
  private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

public void open() 
{

```
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}

public List<String> getQuotes() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM peertable", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public ListView listView;
Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static final String COL_1 = "name";
private static final String COL_2 = "number";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "peertable";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_1, "Karthik");
    values.put(COL_2, 1237894560);
    database.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);

    List<String> data = databaseAccess.getQuotes();
    databaseAccess.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    this.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

In MainActivity, I am trying to insert the query.

Error Log:

```
 Process: com.synergy.externaldatabase, PID: 11828
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.synergy.externaldatabase/com.synergy.externaldatabase.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.synergy.externaldatabase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6915)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize `database` but use it here:

```
database.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
```

The `database` field declared in `DatabaseAccess` is not the same as the one declared in `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 databaseAccess.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
```